# Why does this error keep popping up? Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, errors

This is my code:

```
\begin{frame}{Ponavljanje - područje definicije}
\section{Ponavljanje - područje definicije}
\subsection{Polinomi}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Polinomi
\end{enumerate}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{polinomi (1)}
$$
D_{f} = \mathbb{R} , R_{f} = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{R} & n $ neparan$ \\
[o, + \infty > & n $ paran$
\end{cases}
$$

\end{frame}
```

Error: `Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}`

Comment: Please start choosing appropriate titles. Prefixes like ["Why does this error keep popping up?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A118446+is%3Aquestion) doesn't add value.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX uses `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` for displayed math equations, see: [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/16967)

`\mathbb` and environment `cases` are supported by package `amsmath`. The following works without error:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfencoding=auto}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Ponavljanje - područje definicije}
\section{Ponavljanje - područje definicije}
\subsection{Polinomi}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Polinomi
\end{enumerate}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a}
\[
D_{f} = \mathbb{R} , R_{f} = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{R} & n $ neparan$ \\
[o, + \infty > & n $ paran$
\end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW, TeX shows the undefined command sequence in the error message at the end of the line that starts with the line number.

Comment: Why are `\section{...}` and `\subsection{...}` inside the frame environment?

Comment: @user94293 Merely copied from the question.